# Looping through large DynamicFrame for outputting to S3 to get around 'maxResultSize' error

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, etl, aws-glue

I have a large DynamicFrame in an AWS Glue ETL Job. When trying to output this data to S3 it fails as the task is too large.

Error:

> Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of 3225 tasks (1024.0 MB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MB)

I believe a good solution for this will be to separate my DynamicFrame by date, and loop through data from each date and output it in smaller chunks. Perhaps something like:

```
for eventDateParam in mapped_datasource0_general.eventDate:
    partitioned_dataframe_general = mapped_datasource0_general.where(eventDate = eventDateParam)
    dataoutput_general = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = partitioned_dataframe_general, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": glue_relationalize_output_s3_path_general, "partitionKeys": ["eventDate"]}, format = "parquet", transformation_ctx = "dataoutput_general")
```

I am relatively new to AWS Glue and bumping into a variety of errors trying to find a workaround here. Any suggestions appreciated.

Cheers!

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Edit:

Longer tracestack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "script_2018-06-19-22-36-11.py", line 63, in <module>
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = partitioned_mapped_personal_DF, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": glue_relationalize_output_s3_path_personal, "partitionKeys": ["eventDate"]}, format = "parquet", transformation_ctx = "dataoutput_personal")
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1529446917701_0002/container_1529446917701_0002_01_000001/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/dynamicframe.py", line 572, in from_options
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1529446917701_0002/container_1529446917701_0002_01_000001/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/context.py", line 191, in write_dynamic_frame_from_options
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1529446917701_0002/container_1529446917701_0002_01_000001/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/context.py", line 214, in write_from_options
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1529446917701_0002/container_1529446917701_0002_01_000001/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/data_sink.py", line 32, in write
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1529446917701_0002/container_1529446917701_0002_01_000001/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/data_sink.py", line 28, in writeFrame
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1529446917701_0002/container_1529446917701_0002_01_000001/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1529446917701_0002/container_1529446917701_0002_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1529446917701_0002/container_1529446917701_0002_01_000001/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1198.pyWriteDynamicFrame.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:213)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:145)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.writeInFileFormat(DataSource.scala:435)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:471)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:609)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:233)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.SparkSQLDataSink.writeDynamicFrame(DataSink.scala:123)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.DataSink.pyWriteDynamicFrame(DataSink.scala:38)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of 3109 tasks (1024.3 MB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MB)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1517)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1505)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1732)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1687)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1676)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2029)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:186)
... 45 more
```

And the relevant lines of code:

```
listOfDistinctsPersonal = mapped_personal.select("eventDate").distinct()

#LOOP WRITE PERSONAL
for eventDateParam in listOfDistinctsPersonal:
    partitioned_mapped_personal = mapped_personal.where(col("eventDate") == eventDateParam)
    partitioned_mapped_personal_DF = DynamicFrame.fromDF(partitioned_mapped_personal, glueContext, "partitioned_mapped_personal_DF")
    glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = partitioned_mapped_personal_DF, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": glue_relationalize_output_s3_path_personal, "partitionKeys": ["eventDate"]}, format = "parquet", transformation_ctx = "dataoutput_personal")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're saying you want to output data to S3. If you're not doing heavy aggregations (groupBy or join) the size of your `DataFrame`/`DynamicFrame` should not matter - it will just take longer to move the data.

The error you're getting indicates that you are trying to stream your DataFrame to the driver:

The `spark.driver.maxResultSize` is a configuration controlling now much data can be streamed back to driver from executors. This usually happens when you call `DataFrame.collect` or `DataFrame.collectAsList`. Check [Spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#application-properties) for more details.

You said you're getting various errors - maybe your job is raising an error somewhere else? Could you share all of your glue code? and maybe also the stacktrace of the error?

When checking the Cloud Watch logs, make sure you change the view from *Row* to *Text*:
[image]

Comment: The various errors I'm getting are related to my attempted fix.

Additional sample from the original error log:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
File "script_2018-06-14-15-45-26.py", line 74, in <module>
dataoutput_personal = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = mapped_datasource0_personal, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": glue_relationalize_output_s3_path_personal, "partitionKeys": ["eventDate"]}, format = "parquet", transformation_ctx = "dataoutput_personal")`

Comment: Would removing the `dataoutput_personal = ` help me here? Is that the equivalent of `.collect()`? Considering this is the final action of the script so I don't actually use that DynamicFrame going forwards.

Comment: I don't think that `write_dynamic_frame` would call `collect` internally. Are you not doing any transformation on `mapped_datasource0_personal` dataframe?

Comment: `mapped_datasource0_personal` is converted from a PySpark dataframe just before the output line in the code: `mapped_datasource0_personal = DynamicFrame.fromDF(mapped_personal, glueContext, "mapped_datasource0_personal")`

Is writing the dynamic frame that I'm outputting to S3 to a new DynamicFrame potentially causing problems?

And thank you so much for your help @botchniaque

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the job runs perfectly on a smaller sample dataset.
I have looped my output by a date parameter in the data so it's in smaller chunks and removed the `dataoutput_personal = ` since it does nothing functionally. Now fails with a new error, this time no traceback in the logs but the error message in the AWS Glue UI is: `Command failed with exit code 1`. Struggling to find anything helpful with that sadly.

Comment: @EricKeen to see something useful in the logs in CloudWatch you have to change the log view from _Row_ to _Text_, because one row of glue logs is always multiline - I update my answer with a screenshot.

Comment: Looking through the specific error logs I see no tracebacks or anything helpful. In the general logs there are some instances of: `18/06/18 19:08:46 INFO S3NativeFileSystem: Encountered an exception while reading 'Events_10422/LIVE/EVENTS_10424_146270827.csv.gz', will retry by attempting to reopen stream.
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out`. I've tried running my job on a subset of these files and it runs fine. No other obvious issues but the logs are massive! I do have job bookmarking enabled which I've read can be related to this `exit code 1`. Still digging...

Comment: I have edited my original question to add a longer traceback.

Comment: I have also added the code that causes this error, hopefully any of this is somewhat helpful. This is from an attempted rerun with bookmarking disabled, but ran into the same error as before.

Comment: Do you guys have any idea like how to split rows based on row count in DynamicFrame? I have a scenario where I need to split the result into 4 parts based on the total number of rows. I searched the documents and found that I could only split it by applying specific condition on a field.